# Getting NullPointerException when running Spark Code in Zeppelin 0.7.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have installed `Zeppelin 0.7.1`. When I tried to execute the Example spark program(which was available with `Zeppelin Tutorial` notebook), I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:391)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:380)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:828)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:483)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have also setup the config file(`zeppelin-env.sh`) to point to my Spark installation & Hadoop configuration directory

```
export SPARK_HOME="/${homedir}/sk"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/${homedir}/hp/etc/hadoop"
```

The Spark version I am using is 2.1.0 & Hadoop is 2.7.3

Also I am using the default Spark Interpreter Configuration(so Spark is set to run in `Local mode`)

Am I missing something here?

PS : I am able to connect to spark from the Terminal using `spark-shell`

Answer (score 12):

Just now I got solution of this issue for Zeppelin-0.7.2:

> Root Cause is : Spark trying to setup Hive context, but hdfs services
>   is not running, that's why HiveContext become null and throwing null
>   pointer exception.

**Solution:**
1. Setup Saprk Home [optional] and HDFS.
2. Run HDFS service
3. Restart zeppelin server
**OR**
1. Go to Zeppelin's Interpreter settings.
2. Select Spark Interpreter
3. `zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext = false`

Comment: The HiveContext did it for me as well!

Comment: Dear @RajeevRathor and @BenjaminBaron, I don't intend to be rude but I'm sure upvoting the answer serves the same purpose as writing those comments. When you hover over `add a comment`, the popup says `.. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".` FYI, this solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9):

Finally, I am able to find out the reason. When I checked the logs in ZL_HOME/logs directory, find out it seems to be the Spark Driver binding error. Added the following property in Spark Interpreter Binding and works good now...

[image]

PS : Looks like this issue comes up mainly if you connect to VPN...and I do connect to VPN

Comment: I too saw this problem appear on Zeppelin 0.8 running on a VM; everything was working fine until one of the VM's (unrelated) network adapters changed address, and only a restart got Zeppelin back to work...

Answer (score 2):

Did you set right `SPARK_HOME`? Just wondered what `sk` is in your

`export SPARK_HOME="/${homedir}/sk"`

(I just wanted to comment below your question but couldn't, due to my lack of reputation)

Comment: yes, that is where I have installed Spark :). that is the Home directory of Spark installation

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding this line at the top in file common.sh
 in dir  zeppelin-0.6.1  then bin

open common.sh
and add command in the top of file set :

`unset CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 0):

```
    enterCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 74 more
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 71 more
 INFO [2017-11-20 17:51:55,288] ({pool-2-thread-4} SparkInterpreter.java[createSparkSession]:369) - Created Spark session with Hive support
ERROR [2017-11-20 17:51:55,290] ({pool-2-thread-4} Job.java[run]:181) - Job failed code here
```

It looks like Hive Metastore service not started. You can start the Metastore service and try again.

```
hive --service metastore
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exactly same exception for zepelline 0.7.2 version on window 7. I had to do multiple changes into the configuration to make it work.

First rename the zeppelin-env.cmd.template to zeppelin-env.cmd. Add the env variable for PYTHONPATH. The file can be located at %ZEPPELIN_HOME%/conf folder.

```
set PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\pyspark.zip
```

Open the zeppelin.cmd from location %ZEPPELIN_HOME%/bin to add a %SPARK_HOME% and %ZEPPELIN_HOME%. Those will be the first lines in the instruction. The value for %SPARK_HOME% was configured as blank as I was using the embedded spark library.I added %ZEPPELIN_HOME% to make sure this env is configured at the initial stage of startup.

```
set SPARK_HOME=
set ZEPPELIN_HOME=<PATH to zeppelin installed folder>
```

Next we will have to copy all the jar and pySpark from the %spark_home%/ to zeppeline folder.

```
cp %SPARK_HOME%/jar/*.jar %ZEPPELIN_HOME%/interpreter/spark
cp %SPARK_HOME%/python/pyspark %ZEPPELIN_HOME%/interpreter/spark/pyspark
```

I wasn't starting the **interpreter.cmd** while accessing the notebook. This was causing the nullpointer exception. I opened two command prompt and in one cmd I started zeppeline.cmd and in the other interpreter.cmd.

We have to specify two additional input port and path to zeppeline local_repo in command line. You can get the path to local_repo in zeppeline spark interpreter page. Use exactly same path to start the interpreter.cmd.

```
interpreter.cmd  -d %ZEPPELIN_HOME%\interpreter\spark\ -p 5050  -l %ZEPPELIN_HOME%\local-repo\2D64VMYZE
```

The host and port needs to be specified in the spark interpreter page in zepelline ui. Select the Connect to external Process

```
HOST : localhost
PORT : 5050
```

Once all these on configuration are created, on next step we can save and restart the spark interpreter. Create a new notebook and type sc.version. 
It will publish the spark version. Zeppeline 0.7.2 doesn't support spark 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

On AWS EMR the issue was memory. I had to manually set lower value for `spark.executor.memory` in the Interpeter for Spark using the UI of Zeppelin.

The value varies based on your instance size. 
The best is to check the logs located in the `/mnt/var/log/zeppelin/` folder.

In my case the underlying error was:

```
Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (6144+614 MB) is above the max threshold (6144 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.
```

That helped me understand why it was failing and what I can do to fix it.

Note:

This happened because I was starting an instance with HBase which limits the available memory. See the defaults for instance size [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html).

Comment: I downvoted because while this may be useful, this error is not part of the stacktrace and it is not part of the question.

Comment: @Marc-OlivierTiteux I beg to differ. The `NullPointerException` does happen when you run the application on Zeppelin. Namely, that is the exception you get on the front end. When you dig into logs, as I did, you can see that `NullPointerException` was masking the `IllegalArgumentException` I mentioned above.
If you are having the same issue as a poster, you should check the logs in the path above.

Comment: very different in my case. A custom package was installed on the cluster and triggered the error.

I am not saying you have the same pattern. I am saying that the answer does not match the stacktrace in the OP did not have this.

Comment: @Marc-OlivierTiteux It did match. The `NullPointerException` on the frontend can be caused by *multiple* other issues, one of which is the one I had. To reiterate: I had the **exact same stacktrace as the poster**, but when you dig into logs, you can see that `NullPointerException` was caused by other service failing with `IllegalArgumentException` where the `Zeppelin` expected the result to not be `null`. You are basically penalising me because your `NullPointerException` wasn't solved by my answer. The OP didn't accept any of the answers, so should they all get negative points?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your NameNode have gone in safe mode.

check with below syntax:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get
```

to leave from safe mode use below command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using incorrect interpreter. Switched from `%spark.ipyspark` to `%pyspark`.

Answer (score -2):

Seems to be bug in Zeppelin 0.7.1.  Works fine in 0.7.2.

Comment: I think this is a configuration problem and will happen with any version of Zeppelin.  I saw this in Zeppelin 0.7.2

Comment: same thing in 0.7.3