# Spark: Fat-JAR crashing Zeppelin with NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, sbt-assembly

**Note: This is NOT a duplicate of [Getting NullPointerException when running Spark Code in Zeppelin 0.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289067/getting-nullpointerexception-when-running-spark-code-in-zeppelin-0-7-1)**

---

I've run into this *roadblock* in `Apache Zeppelin` on `Amazon EMR`. I'm trying to load a **fat-jar** (located on `Amazon S3`) into `Spark interpreter`. Once the *fat-jar* is loaded, `Zeppelin`'s `Spark interpreter` refuses to work with following stack-trace

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:398)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:387)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:843)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Even a *simple* `Scala` statement like `val str: String = "sample string"` that *doesn't access anything* from the *jar* produces the above *error-log*. Removing the *jar* from *interpreter's dependencies* fixes the issue; so clearly, **it has something to do with the jar only**.

The `fat-jar` in question has been generated by `Jenkins` using `sbt assembly`. The *project* (who's *fat-jar* I'm loading) contains two `submodules` inside a *parent module*.

---

While sharing the complete `build.sbt` files and *dependency files* of all 3 submodules would be impractical, I'm enclosing an **exhaustive list of all dependencies and configurations** used in the submodules.

**AWS dependencies**

- `"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.218"`
- `"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-emr" % "1.11.218"`
- `"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-ec2" % "1.11.218"`

**Spark dependencies** (given as *provided* `allSparkdependencies.map(_ % "provided")`)

- `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"`
- `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"`
- `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.0"`
- `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0"`

**Testing dependencies**

- `"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % Test`
- `"com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.2.0_0.7.2" % "test"`

**Other dependencies**

- `"com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.7.0"`
- `"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"`
- `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.6"`
- `"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9"`
- `"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.41"`
- `"com.github.gilbertw1" %% "slack-scala-client" % "0.2.2"`
- `"org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0"`

**Framework versions**

- `Scala v2.11.11`
- `SBT v1.0.3`
- `Spark v2.2.0`
- `Zeppelin v0.7.3`

**SBT Configurations**

```
// cache options
offline := false
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)

// aggregate options
aggregate in assembly := false
aggregate in update := false

// fork options
fork in Test := true

// merge strategy
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.startsWith("META-INF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", _@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", _@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "jboss", _@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: There is something in the aws-*.jar that is breaking Zeppelin and I also can't figure out what...

Comment: Solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289067/getting-nullpointerexception-when-running-spark-code-in-zeppelin-0-7-1) are either not working or are *(most-probably)* inapplicable in my scenario.

Comment: I suggest that you add this to your question so it doesn't get flagged as a dupe

Comment: **@eliasah** I'd like to tell you that another *jar* that also contains the 2 **submodules** (that I have in this problematic jar) works just fine. And one of those submodules contains the `aws-*.jar` dependencies. So at least in my case, it's unlikely that `aws-*.jar` are the culprit.

Comment: @y2k-shubham Did you ever find out the solution? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Comment: **@ss85** please do convey if the *proposed solution* worked for you and / or whatever *additional changes* you made to fix the *glitch*

Answer (score 0):

While the problem got fixed, honestly speaking I was **unable to drill down to the root cause** of it (and hence a *real solution* for it). After rigorously going through *forums* in vain, I ended up *manually* comparing (and *re-aligning*) my code (`git diff`) with the last known working `build`. (!)

It's been a while since then and now when I check my `git` *history*, I find it (the `commit` that fixed this problem) contains either *refactoring* or *build-related stuff*. Therefore my best guess is that it was a **build-related issue**. I'm putting down all changes that I made to `build.sbt`.

I re-iterate that I cannot establish if it was for these particular modifications that the issue got fixed, so keep looking. I'll keep this question open until a *conclusive* cause (and solution) is found.

---

Mark the following *dependencies* as `provided` as told [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/wiki/%5BSBT%5D-How-to-use-provided-libraries-in-run-configurations):

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
"com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.2.0_0.7.2" % "test"
```

*Override* the following [`fasterxml.jackson`](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.fasterxml) *dependencies*:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.5"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" %
"2.6.5"
```

---

I'd like to point out one particular thing: the following [`LogBack` dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic) that I initially held culprit actually had nothing to do with this (we had faced issues with `LogBack` in the past, so it suited us to blame it). While we removed it at the time of *resolution*, we've added it back since then.

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

Comment: [Zeppelin-2475](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2475) seems related to this

Comment: Looks like it was `jackson` which was annoying `Zeppelin` all this while; i just came across [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2475?focusedCommentId=16330414&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16330414) on **[Zeppelin-2475]**